# Exception: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: jpa.tenants.DataSourceConfig

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I folloowing below link to understand
 “[https://medium.com/swlh/multi-tenancy-implementation-using-spring-boot-hibernate-6a8e3ecb251a”](https://medium.com/swlh/multi-tenancy-implementation-using-spring-boot-hibernate-6a8e3ecb251a%E2%80%9D) tutorial

```
package jpa.tenants;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Component
public class DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl extends AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource defaultDS;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    private Map<String, DataSource> map = new HashMap<>();

    boolean init = false;

    private String DEFAULT_TENANT_ID="1";

    @PostConstruct
    public void load() {
        map.put(DEFAULT_TENANT_ID, defaultDS);
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectAnyDataSource() {
        return map.get(DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier) {
        if (!init) {
            init = true;
            TenantDataSource tenantDataSource = context.getBean(TenantDataSource.class);
            map.putAll(tenantDataSource.getAll());
        }
        return map.get(tenantIdentifier) != null ? map.get(tenantIdentifier) : map.get(DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
    }
}
```

Resulting into below exception:

> ```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
> ```
>
> resource [jpa/tenants/HibernateConfig.class]: Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>   No identifier specified for entity: jpa.tenants.DataSourceConfig
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
>   [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at jpa.JpaExample.main(JpaExample.java:10) [classes/:na]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>         at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: jpa.tenants.DataSourceConfig
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:266)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:211)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:781)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:254)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:230)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:273)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
>         ... 21 common frames omitted

```
    'This is my DataSourceConfig Class:-'

    package jpa.tenants;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

    import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;
    import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

    @Entity
    @Table(appliesTo= "DATASOURCECONFIG")
    public class DataSourceConfig {

        @Id
        @JsonIgnore
        @Column(name="id", nullable=false)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        private String name;
        private String url;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private String driverClassName;
        private boolean initialize;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getDriverClassName() {
            return driverClassName;
        }

        public void setDriverClassName(String driverClassName) {
            this.driverClassName = driverClassName;
        }

        public boolean isInitialize() {
            return initialize;
        }

        public void setInitialize(boolean initialize) {
            this.initialize = initialize;
        }
    }

    ----------------------------------------


----------


   ' Any help is highly appriciated thanks..'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Id` annotation in the class `DataSourceConfig` is imported from the wrong package:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
```

This must be

```
import javax.persistence.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove @Entity tag for the class which is going to be Embedded.

Then it works...!